# LEFT JOIN is not showing null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to show projects even if there are no active jobs using LEFT JOIN, but it doesn't seem to work. I suspect it's an obvious mistake so please help:

```
SELECT
  `projects`.`id` AS `project_id`,
  `projects`.`name` AS `project_name`,
  `jobs`.`id` AS `job_id`,
  `jobs`.`title` AS `job_title`,
  `jobs`.`description` AS `job_description`
FROM
  `projects`
  LEFT JOIN `jobs` ON `projects`.`id` = `jobs`.`project_id`
WHERE
  `projects`.`company_id` = 29
  AND `jobs`.`active` = 0
ORDER BY
  `projects`.`name`,
  `jobs`.`title` asc
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/305373/1

Desired outcome would be having a list of projects including these without matching jobs (so with `null` value).

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the `where` condition on `jobs` to the `on`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM `projects` LEFT JOIN
     `jobs` 
     ON `projects`.`id` = `jobs`.`project_id` AND
        `jobs`.`active` = 0
WHERE `projects`.`company_id` = 29
```

The comparison on `jobs`.`active` turns the outer join into an inner join, because `NULL` values are not matched.

Answer (score 3):

Put `where` clause with `ON` clause :

```
SELECT . . .
FROM `projects` LEFT JOIN 
      `jobs` 
      ON `projects`.`id` = `jobs`.`project_id` AND 
         `jobs`.`active` = 0
WHERE `projects`.`company_id` = 29;
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `jobs.activve=0` from where  put it on join condition

```
SELECT
  `projects`.`id` AS `project_id`,
  `projects`.`name` AS `project_name`,
  `jobs`.`id` AS `job_id`,
  `jobs`.`title` AS `job_title`,
  `jobs`.`description` AS `job_description`
FROM
  `projects`
  LEFT JOIN `jobs` ON `projects`.`id` = `jobs`.`project_id` and job.active=0
WHERE
  `projects`.`company_id` = 29

ORDER BY
  `projects`.`name`,
  `jobs`.`title` asc
```

cause your where condition makes it  inner join